# Estou tentando preencher um formulario no vba e não vai pq?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

alguem sabe como preencher um google forms com vba , eu consegui algumas linhas mas ele não preencher tudo ,eu consigo preencher, no inspecionar elementos aparece preenchido mas não preenche na pagina

```
Public Sub ConectaWeb()
On Error Resume Next
Dim endereço As String
Dim mostra As Boolean

Dim i, n, x As Integer
endereço = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc-d6XfqSS_-P2SCRiIJMKU477NPlzFnkjVHe0RqO2DMSc4xA/viewform"
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate (endereço)
While IE.ReadyState <> 4
Wend
IE.Visible = True

IE.document.getElementsByName("entry.666457405")(0).Value = "20"
IE.document.getElementsByName("entry.1010616991")(0).Value = "30"
IE.document.getElementsByName("entry.452700562")(0).Value = "45"
IE.document.getElementsByName("entry.1857809015")(0).Value = "nome"
IE.document.getElementsByName("entry.2073241118")(0).Value = "cargo"
IE.document.getElementsByName("entry.2015582786")(0).Value = "5356645"

IE.document.forms.Item(0).submit
   
While IE.ReadyState <> 4
Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

consegui fazer sozinho , voce tem que pegar pelas classes e determinar o item no fnal depois do nome da classe porque o google forms pra ajudar nao especifica os campos por id ou name por exemplo id="email" ou name="name"

```
`Public Sub ConectaWeb()
On Error Resume Next
Dim endereço As String
Dim mostra As Boolean

Dim i, n, x As Integer
endereço = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc-d6XfqSS_-P2SCRiIJMKU477NPlzFnkjVHe0RqO2DMSc4xA/viewform"
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate (endereço)
While IE.ReadyState <> 4
Wend
IE.Visible = True

'Analista Argus
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputPlaceholder exportLabel")(0).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput")(0).Value = "João"


'Detalhe Quantidade de ligações
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPapertextareaPlaceholder exportLabel")(0).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPapertextareaInput exportTextarea")(0).Value = "3"

'Com quem conseguiu contato
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPapertextareaPlaceholder exportLabel")(1).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPapertextareaInput exportTextarea")(1).Value = "joaozinho"

'Qual a tratativa dada pelo cliente
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPapertextareaPlaceholder exportLabel")(2).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPapertextareaInput exportTextarea")(2).Value = "nenhuma"


'Operação
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputPlaceholder exportLabel")(1).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput")(1).Value = "ambev"

'Frota
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputPlaceholder exportLabel")(2).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput")(2).Value = "fob4343"



'Tipo 1 Evento
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputPlaceholder exportLabel")(18).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput")(18).Value = "sonolencia"


'Tipo 2 Evento
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputPlaceholder exportLabel")(19).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput")(19).Value = "falso"

'Quantidade Evento tipo1
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputPlaceholder exportLabel")(20).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput")(20).Value = "34"

'Quantidade Evento tipo 2
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputPlaceholder exportLabel")(21).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput")(21).Value = "1"

'Indicador Intervenção
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputPlaceholder exportLabel")(22).innerhtml = ""
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput")(22).Value = "1,5"

   
While IE.ReadyState <> 4
Wend
End Sub
```